# Magento 2 : Required fields in checkout are no longer required

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, checkout, uicomponent, form-validation

I have a strange issue in Magento 2 (2.1.9), and I was wondering if anyone encountered something like this before. The required fields in the checkout usually have a `required`-class, but for some reason they now have a class called `_required`. This goes for all input elements. Validation is still applied, so if I click 'Next' or tab-focus to another input-field I still get the errors that the fields are required.

Anyone encountered this before and/or know what might cause this? I only have 2 external modules, but disabling these modules make no difference.